# Creating a ToolElement for every object JointJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jointjs

I am trying to create a sort of a Tool menu for every object - when you click or hover over an element, it shows several actions that could be done: delete, rotate, enlarge, link,  etc.

I have used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153345/how-to-give-jointjs-elements-a-remove-tool/) as the guideline - and was able to add and extend the ToolElement itself, with the help of the [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kj4bqczd/3/).

However, after that I got stuck on the functionality of linking. What I want to do is the green arrow. And when I click and drag the green arrow, I want the link to start dragging from the object, just like a port, only from the object itself.

[image: rendering of the tool element]

I tried reading the documentation, but it had no traces of how to drag from the element.

There was a solution where you could add the `magnet : true` attribute to text, and that way when you click on the object - you drag it, and when you click on the text, you start dragging the link.

In another solution below, I tried manually adding the magnet to the circle. Visually, it somewhat does what I need, but source of the link is always that green circle, even when it disappears, and when calling the object ti check for links, it does not give me those links.

```
joint.shapes.tm.toolElement = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({

    toolMarkup: ['<g class="element-tools">',
        '<g class="element-tool-remove"><circle fill="red" r="11"/>',
        '<path transform="scale(.8) translate(-16, -16)" d="M24.778,21.419 19.276,15.917 24.777,10.415 21.949,7.585 16.447,13.087 10.945,7.585 8.117,10.415 13.618,15.917 8.116,21.419 10.946,24.248 16.447,18.746 21.948,24.248z"/>',
        '<title>Remove this element from the model</title>',
        '</g>',

        '<g class="element-tool-link"><circle magnet="true" fill="green" r="11" cx="25" />',
        '<path transform="scale(.8) translate(15, -16)" d="M24.778,21.419 19.276,15.917 24.777,10.415 21.949,7.585 16.447,13.087 10.945,7.585 8.117,10.415 13.618,15.917 8.116,21.419 10.946,24.248 16.447,18.746 21.948,24.248z"/>',
        '<title>Link element</title>',
        '</g>',

        '</g>'].join(''),

   defaults: ...

});
```

I think my bottomline question is to figure out how to use the magnet property on the green arrow and tie it to the object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry @Alexey but I can't work out how to do it :o( In my solution I don't drag from the green arrow, I just click it and then click the element I want to link to. Maybe this question can give you some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605148/jointjs-element-with-ports-and-tool-items-delete-settings-etc

Comment: Well, thank you, anyway =) Your previous answers were great idea boosters