# Delete tool/icon in jointjs

Tags: backbone.js, svg, jointjs

I have create a circle shape as a delete tool to delete shapes. I got the information from this link: [JointJS Element with ports and tool items (delete, settings etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605148/jointjs-element-with-ports-and-tool-items-delete-settings-etc)

Almost implemented it correctly but some how the delete shape(circle) doesn't have `'X'` mark on it and also delete event is not fired. If any body worked on it already, please guide me here. Thanks

Code:

```
var clientX, clientY, offsetX, offsetY;
var x, y;
var shapeId = "";
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#canvas'),
    id: 'myPaper',
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1,
    defaultLink: new joint.shapes.devs.Link({
        router: {name: 'orthogonal', args: {maximumLoops: 1000, excludeTypes: ['container']}},
        connector: {name: 'rounded'},
        attrs: {'.marker-target': {d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z'}},
        labels: [{position: .5, attrs: {text: {text: 'label', 'font-size': '13', 'stroke': 'black', 'stroke-width': '0.1'}}}]
    }),
    validateConnection: function (cellViewS, magnetS, cellViewT, magnetT, end, linkView) {
        if (magnetS && magnetS.getAttribute('type') === 'input')
            return true;
        if (cellViewS === cellViewT)
            return false;
        return (magnetS !== magnetT);
        return magnetT && magnetT.getAttribute('type') === 'input';
    },
    markAvailable: true
});

joint.shapes.devs.TooledModel = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend(_.extend({}, joint.plugins.TooledModelInterface, {
//    markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect class="body"/></g><text class="t"/><g class="inPorts"/><g class="outPorts"/><g class="moveTool"/><g class="resizeTool"/><g class="portsTool"/></g>',
markup: ['<g class="rotatable">',
            '<g class="scalable">',
                '<rect class="body"/>',
                '<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="translate(-549.49953,-824.87393)" id="layer1">',
                    '<g transform="matrix(0.933025,0,0,-0.2986125,549.49953,846.37362)" id="g3553">',
                      '<g transform="scale(0.98976,3.0047)" id="g3555">',
                        '<g clip-path="url(#clipPath3559)" id="g3557">',
                          '<path  d="M24.778,21.419 19.276,15.917 24.777,10.415 21.949,7.585 16.447,13.087 10.945,7.585 8.117,10.415 13.618,15.917 8.116,21.419 10.946,24.248 16.447,18.746 21.948,24.248z" id="path3563" style="fill:#b8cde8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"/>',
                        '</g>',
                      '</g>',
                    '</g>',
                '</g>',
            '</g>',
            '<text class="t"/>',
            '<g class="inPorts"/>',
            '<g class="outPorts"/>',
            '<g class="moveTool"/>',
            '<g class="resizeTool"/>',
            '<g class="portsTool"/>',
            '<g class="deleteTool"/>',
            '<circle class="deleteTool" id="deleteTool" fill="red" r="8"/>',
            '<title class="tooltip"/>',
        '</g>'].join(''),
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type: 'devs.TooledModel',
        position: {x: 200, y: 100},
        size: {width: 71, height: 625},
        attrs: {
//            '.label': {text: ""},
            'text': {'font-size': 14, text: '', 'ref-x': .5, 'ref-y': .5, ref: '.body', 'y-alignment': 'middle', 'x-alignment': 'middle', fill: 'black', 'font-weight': 'normal', 'font-family': 'Arial, helvetica, sans-serif'},
            rect: {stroke: '#008B8B', fill: '#EEEEEE', 'stroke-width': 2}, '.': {magnet: false},
            '.inPorts circle': {type: 'input'},
            '.outPorts circle': {type: 'output'},
            '.port-body': {r: 3},
            '.body': {
            width: 151, height: 151,
            stroke: 'none'
        },
        }
    }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
}
));
joint.shapes.devs.TooledModelView = joint.shapes.devs.ModelView.extend(joint.plugins.TooledViewInterface);

function getId(id)
{
    shapeId = id;
    console.log(shapeId);
}
function createShape(event)
{
    var $stageContainer = $("#canvas");
    var stageOffset = $stageContainer.offset();
    clientX = event.clientX;
    clientY = event.clientY;
    offsetX = stageOffset.left;
    offsetY = stageOffset.top;
    x = clientX - offsetX;
    y = clientY - offsetY;

    switch (shapeId)
    {
        case('newTask'):
            createRect(x, y);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Nothing to drag");
    }
}
function createRect(x, y)
{
    var rect = new joint.shapes.devs.TooledModel({
        position: {x: x, y: y},
        size: {width: 120, height: 85},
        inPorts: [''],
        outPorts: [''],
        attrs: {
            text: {text: 'Edit me', fill: 'black'},
            rect: {
                fill: '#D6F2FC', rx: 7, ry: 15, opacity: .80, 'stroke-width': 2
            },
            '.inPorts circle': {type: 'input'},
            '.outPorts circle': {type: 'output'},
            '.port-body': {r: 3}
        }
    });
    graph.addCell(rect);
}

// First, unembed the cell that has just been grabbed by the user.
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function (cellView) {
    var cell = cellView.model;
    if (!cell.get('embeds') || cell.get('embeds').length === 0) {
        // Show the dragged element above all the other cells (except when the
        // element is a parent).
        cell.toFront();
        _.invoke(graph.getConnectedLinks(cell), 'toFront');
    }
    if (cell.get('parent')) {
        graph.getCell(cell.get('parent')).unembed(cell);
    }
});
// When the dragged cell is dropped over another cell, let it become a child of the element below.
paper.on('cell:pointerup', function (cellView) {

    if (cellView.model.isLink())
        return;
    var cell = cellView.model;
    var cellViewsBelow = paper.findViewsFromPoint(cell.getBBox().center());
    if (cellViewsBelow.length) {
        // Note that the findViewsFromPoint() returns the view for the `cell` itself.
        var cellViewBelow = _.find(cellViewsBelow, function (c) {
            return c.model.id !== cell.id;
        });
        // Prevent recursive embedding.
        if (cellViewBelow && cellViewBelow.model.get('parent') !== cell.id) {
            cellViewBelow.model.embed(cell);
        }
    }
});
```

Tooled model interface contains:

```
deleteToolMarkup: '<circle fill="red" r="11"/><path transform="scale(.8) translate(-16, -16)" d="M24.778,21.419 19.276,15.917 24.777,10.415 21.949,7.585 16.447,13.087 10.945,7.585 8.117,10.415 13.618,15.917 8.116,21.419 10.946,24.248 16.447,18.746 21.948,24.248z"/><title>Remove this element from the model</title>',
```

joint.plugins.TooledViewInterface contains:

```
 //delete tool
    renderDeleteTool: function () {
        var deleteContainer = this.$('.deleteTool').empty();
        var markup = V(this.model.deleteToolMarkup);
        for (var id in markup)
            deleteContainer.append(markup[id].node);
    },
```