# How to implement drag and connect feature provided by Rappid with pure JointJS?

Tags: jointjs, rappid

There is a feature in Rappid (the paid version of JointJS) which allows you to drag a button from the toolbox of an element and connect that element to another element where you release your mouse button. 
I want to implement this feature with JointJS core library. I've managed to create a tool box with elementTools and added two buttons, one for removing the element and one for this drag and connect feature. 
[The Picture of element with element toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUqMu.png)
The problem is the button for drag fires only when I click on the button. It doesn't allow me to drag and have x, y coordinates of the mouse.
There is a similar question which was left unanswered in stackoverflow: 
[Creating a ToolElement for every object JointJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504323/creating-a-toolelement-for-every-object-jointjs/62643082)

Here is my snippet for the button:

```
const InfoButton = joint.elementTools.Button.extend({
        name: 'info-button',
        options: {
            focusOpacity: 0.5,
            distance: 60,
            action: function (evt: JQueryEventObject, elementView, buttonView) {
                // alert('View id: ' + this.id + '\n' + 'Model id: ' + this.model.id);
                const link = new Models.SequenceFlow();
                link.set('source', { id: elementView.model.get('id') });
                link.set('target', new joint.g.Point(evt.pageX, evt.pageY));
                // const alev = jQuery.Event()
                // evt.preventDefault();
                // paper.trigger('AliEvt', evt);
                link.addTo(model);
                // link.se(this.model);
                // link.target(new joint.g.Point(0, 0));
            },
            markup: [
                {
                    tagName: 'circle',
                    selector: 'button',
                    attributes: {
                        r: 7,
                        fill: '#001DFF',
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                    },
                },
                {
                    tagName: 'path',
                    selector: 'icon',
                    attributes: {
                        d: 'M -2 4 2 4 M 0 3 0 0 M -2 -1 1 -1 M -1 -4 1 -4',
                        fill: 'none',
                        stroke: '#FFFFFF',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                        'pointer-events': 'none',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
});

const infoButton = new InfoButton();

const toolsView = new joint.dia.ToolsView({
    name: 'basic-tools',
    tools: [removeButton, boundaryTool, infoButton],
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.