# Adding remove functionality for elements

Tags: jointjs

I have been looking for a way to add a remove button equivalent to the one existing when hovering over links but for the case of elements.
I cannot find however any *official* way to do it so far.

The nearest I could get was this tutorial http://jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements that shows an example where there's such button but it is always visible instead of appearing only when hovering over the element.

Comment: I would be very interested in that as well. Did you find a way so far?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find it yet...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give JointJS elements a remove tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153345/how-to-give-jointjs-elements-a-remove-tool)